# Problem with Euler angles from YZX Rotation Matrix

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, euler-angles

I've gotten stuck getting my euler angles out my rotation matrix.

My conventions are:

- Left-handed (x right, z back, y up)
- YZX
- Left handed angle rotation

My rotation matrix is built up from Euler angles like (from my code):

```
    var xRotationMatrix = $M([
        [1,  0,   0, 0], 
        [0, cx, -sx, 0], 
        [0, sx,  cx, 0], 
        [0,  0,   0, 1]
    ]);

    var yRotationMatrix = $M([
        [ cy, 0, sy, 0], 
        [  0, 1,  0, 0], 
        [-sy, 0, cy, 0], 
        [  0, 0,  0, 1]
    ]);
    var zRotationMatrix = $M([
        [cz, -sz, 0, 0], 
        [sz,  cz, 0, 0], 
        [ 0,   0, 1, 0], 
        [ 0,   0, 0, 1]
    ]);
```

Which results in a final rotation matrix as:

```
R(YZX) = | cy.cz, -cy.sz.cx + sy.sx,  cy.sz.sx + sy.cx, 0|
         |    sz,             cz.cx,            -cz.sx, 0|
         |-sy.cz,  sy.sz.cx + cy.sx, -sy.sz.sx + cy.cx, 0|
         |     0,                 0,                 0, 1|
```

I'm calculating my euler angles back from this matrix using this code:

```
this.anglesFromMatrix = function(m) {
    var y = 0, x = 0, z = 0;

    if (m.e(2, 1) > 0.999) {
        y = Math.atan2(m.e(1, 3), m.e(3, 3));
        z = Math.PI / 2;
        x = 0;
    } else if (m.e(2, 1) < -0.999) {
        y = Math.atan2(m.e(1, 3), m.e(3, 3));
        z = -Math.PI / 2;
        x = 0;
    } else {
        y = Math.atan2(-m.e(3, 1), -m.e(1, 1));
        x = Math.atan2(-m.e(2, 3), m.e(2, 2));
        z = Math.asin(m.e(2, 1));
    }
    return {theta: this.deg(x), phi: this.deg(y), psi: this.deg(z)};
};
```

I've done the maths backwards and forwards a few times, but I can't see what's wrong.  Any help would hugely appreciated.

Comment: Please ask your question on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would have, but there is far more material on 3D rotation on stackoverflow.  And math.stackexchange claims to be the site "for people studying math or in math related professions".  That excludes me.

Comment: @Scorpi0: This is an appropriate question here. @Brendon: Your code looks OK. I would try the trivial cases: rotate +90 deg around the X axis and then check the result. Then around the Y axis and so on. Only one rotation at a time, and always start from the original state, no consecutive rotations.

Comment: Thanks @Ali - yeah I tried that.  The results were wrong - one rotation affecting two angles.

Comment: I am really disappointed, this question is appropriate here. @Brendon I am glad you finally found the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix and euler angles aren't consistent. It looks like you should be using

```
y = Math.atan2(-m.e(3, 1), m.e(1, 1));
```

instead of

```
y = Math.atan2(-m.e(3, 1), -m.e(1, 1));
```

for the general case (the else branch).

I said "looks like" because -- what language is this? I'm assuming you have the indexing correct for this language. Are you sure about atan2? There is no single convention for atan2. In some programming languages the sine term is the first argument, in others, the cosine term is the first argument.

Comment: I knew it was going to come down to 1 character!  You've made my day.  I've reworked my calculations so many times, but my eyes tend to see what they want.

Answer (score 1):

The last and most important branch of the `anglesFromMatrix` function has a small sign error but otherwise works correctly. Use

```
y = Math.atan2(-m.e(3, 1), m.e(1, 1))
```

since only `m.e(3, 1)` of `m.e(1, 1) = cy.cz` and `m.e(3, 1) = -sy.cz` should be inverted. I haven't checked the other branches for errors.

Beware that since `sz = m.e(2, 1)` has two solutions, the angles `(x, y, z)` used to construct the matrix `m` might not be the same as the angles `(rx, ry, rz)` returned by `anglesFromMatrix(m)`. Instead we can test that the matrix `rm` constructed from `(rx, ry, rz)` does indeed equal `m`.

Comment: Thanks @antonakos.  I've just noticed the two-solution issue (and the issue around poles), and it currently results in some very cool two angle rotation around those points.  But I think I can program around that by driving my rotations with matrices and just using the euler angles to record resting state.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Brendon: The behavior around poles is called "gimbal lock". A common way to avoid this problem in 3D graphics are Quaternions.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this problem extensively to come up with the correct angles for a given matrix. The problem in the math comes from the inability to determine a precise value for the SIN since -SIN(x) = SIN(-x) and this will affect the other values of the matrix. The solution I came up with comes up with two equally valid solutions out of eight possible solutions. I used a standard  Z . Y . X matrix form but it should be adaptable to any matrix. Start by findng the three angles from: X = atan(m32,m33): Y = -asin(m31) : Z = atan(m21,m11) : Then create angles X' = -sign(X)*PI+X : Y'= sign(Y)*PI-Y : Z = -sign(Z)*pi+Z . Using these angles create eight set of angle groups : XYZ : X'YZ : XYZ' : X'YZ' : X'Y'Z' : XY'Z' : X'Y'Z : XY'Z
Use these set to create the eight corresponding matrixes. Then do a sum of the difference between the unknown matrix and each matrix. This is a sum of each element of the unknown minus the same element of the test matrix. After doing this, two of the sums will be zero and those matrixes will represent the solution angles to the original matrix. This works for all possible angle combinations including 0's. As 0's are introduced, more of the eight test matrixes become valid. At 0,0,0 they all become idenity matrixes!
Hope this helps, it worked very well for my application.
Bruce
***update***
After finding problems with Y = -90 or 90 degrees in the solution above. I came up with this solution that seems to reproduce the matrix at all values!
    X = if(or(m31=1,m31=-1),0,atan(m33+1e-24,m32))
    Y = -asin(m31)
    Z = if(or(m31=1,m31=-1),-atan2(m22,m12),atan2(m11+1e-24,m21))
I went the long way around to find this solution, but it wa very enlightening :o)
Hope this helps!
Bruce

Comment: Note: I was attempting to recreate the angles that I used to create the 3D matrix. Using this solution, one of the sets is always the original angles used to create the matrix. Both solutions sets are the exact same matrix with no way to distinguish them from the solution side.